# Vue computed property not updating with updated props

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm not sure why my props aren't updating when I update the data in my parent component. I've tried it out in a fiddle and it works https://jsfiddle.net/f3w69rr6/1/ but it doesn't work in my app.

parent:

```javascript
methods: {
    addToHand(index) {
        let card = this.gameState.playerDeck.splice(index, 1)
        if (this.gameState.playerHand.length < 12)
        {
            // put card into hand
            this.$set(this.gameState, 'playerHand', [...this.gameState.playerHand, card])
            // this.gameState.playerHand.push(card)
        }
        // otherwise discard card
    },
    retrieveDeck() {
        let array = []
        for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            array.push(this.src + "?text=card"+i)
        }
        this.$set(this.gameState, 'playerDeck', array)
    },
},
mounted () {
    this.retrieveDeck()
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        this.addToHand(1)
    }
},
```

putting the data into child via:

```html
<PlayerCards :gameState="gameState" :hand="gameState.playerHand" />
```

child:

```javascript
export default {
    name: 'PlayerCards',
    props: ["gameState", "hand"],
    data() {
        return {
        }
    },
    computed: {
        rows() {
            let cards = this.gameState.playerHand
            let max = 6;
            if (cards.length <= max)
                return [cards]

            var mid = Math.ceil(cards.length / 2);
            let return_value = [cards.slice(0, mid), cards.slice(mid)]
            return return_value
        }
    }
}
```

but the row content is empty.

Update (Updated fiddle):

The problem is with the compute

https://jsfiddle.net/f3w69rr6/1/

Comment: hmm, i think you should fix the type of the props, i dont know if it will affect anything but try it : https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Prop-Validation

Comment: Do you get any value in mounted for `this.gameState` ? In child component?

Comment: @user2486 so when I do a `console.log(this.gameState)` in the browser it will show that it has contents, but if I run a `Object.assign({}, this.gameState)` to something else and log it, it will be empty (as expected upon initialisation). The problem is that it isn't reacting in my app while it seems to work fine in my fiddle. I can post more code if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this was due to a misuse of the `computed` property. Switching it over to `data` and using `this.$set` updates as expected. If I were to use `computed` then setters would be needed. Computed also seems to be more suited for combining/updating `data` properties rather than being a property in and of itself.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not using string templates then you need to use the `kebab-case` equivalent to your `camelCase` prop:

```
<PlayerCards :game-state="gameState" :hand="gameState.playerHand" />
```

The reason it works in your fiddle is because you are using a string template (see: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#camelCase-vs-kebab-case)

Comment: for some reason, it doesn't seem to be the issue as it's still returning an empty array on start. It's more of not updating the child properly

Comment: The problem seems to be with the computed value, though your answer is valid to a portion of my problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your demo in jsfiddle:

```
rows() {
    let cards = this.gameState.playerHand
    let max = 6;
    if (cards.length <= max)
      return [cards]

    var mid = Math.ceil(cards.length / 2);
    let return_value = [cards.slice(0, mid), cards.slice(mid)]
    return return_value      
  }
```

Actually, vue has notified the computed function successfully when `gameState.playerHand` has updated. But you wrapped the computed property: `rows` into an array, like: `[cards]` and `[cards.slice(0, mid), cards.slice(mid)]`. And obviously, the `rows.length` will be `1` or `2`.